# Content generated with external tool

Tags: html

Our company switched from pure HTML-based intranet to SharePoint. In the old days, I have created an HTML page that was dynamically generated in another tool (Matlab). Now I am asked to put the same content into our SharePoint site. I can still simply link to an external HTML page. But I wonder if I can actually embedd this content inside my SharePoint pages and what is the best way to do it. The content is just a 2-level list with text and hyperlinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an WebPart called PageViewer-WebPart you can use for this purpose.

Here's some reference for that: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7f61feec-9b3d-4805-a960-07636ba59527

You may have to take care of the 'SAMEORIGIN' security, but there are a lot of references on how to solve this.

Comment: Looks like a possible solution! I would prefer the style of the text to be inherited from the SharePoint page, but I can definitely live with it. However, is there a way to make this web part as high as its content? Otherwise it really looks like an embedded page rather than embedded content. Microsoft's help is not very helpful: "Height Specifies the height of the Web Part". I do not want to specify it.

Comment: Sadly the only option for this is adding some JS intelligence to the page. Here's some reference for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975810/make-iframe-automatically-adjust-height-according-to-the-contents-without-using

Comment: Will try, thanks. I've just found another problem: With Page Viewer, the links I have in my content open inside the same web-part. I'd like the browser to just go to the linked page. Is it possible? I would like my content to appear as an integral part of the page rather than an embedded external page.

Comment: To get this result you need to set the `target` attribute foreach link in your referenced page to `target="_blank"`. I don't know your HTML-generator, but maybe you can specify this here. 
If not you could use some JS intelligence again. Here's some reference for that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890699/get-all-links-inside-iframe-and-add-blank-target-attribute

Comment: Yes, I can add "blank" but it makes the links open in a new tab. A native link in SharePoint opens the page in the same tab. In my Chrome, it's even more weird: the link does open in the same tab, but the history is reset (no way to go "back"). Anyway, thanks for the suggestion. I think it's good enough for now. SharePoint is evil anyway (I just saw the HTML code it generates for the first time, it's unbelievable :))

Comment: Ah well I misunderstood you - if you want to open the link in the host window set `target` to `_parent`. Here you can find all options for `target` - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp. And yea SP is evil, but evil things are there to be tamed ;)